# Withdraw from wallet

Tags: smart-contract-wallets

I have a contract address that I have revoked with ETH200.CC.  USDT balance is still sitting in the miner.  I cannot access my wallet or Withdraw able amount due to a pledge period.  How can I access my wallet?

Comment: Hi Linda. I'm not sure I understand your question. Could you please elaborate? Thanks

Comment: My contract with ETH200.CC was up on 11/15/22.  I have money in my wallet and in withdrawable.  Since there is no more mining with ETH200.CC why is it saying I cannot withdraw during a Pledge period?  There should not be anymore pledge periods.

Comment: This is concerning the Crypto mining with ETH200.CC.

Comment: It is a highly suspicious site. The audit buttons do not work. There supposed to be a "Terms of Service" document but it is missing. No links to social media. No support email.

Comment: If that's true then why is there money in my Contract, Wallet and in Withdrawable?